# MySQL select males and females under 21

Tags: mysql, split

How would I split males and females and count those under 21?

[image]

So far I have this (but the values are not correct):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT( if(gender='M', 1, 0) ) AS males, 
    COUNT( if(gender='F', 1, 0) ) AS females 
FROM 
    dependent
WHERE 
    YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(dob) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(dob, 5)) < 21
```

output should be like this:

Males | Females

1 | 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to count different values is using GROUP BY.  You will get multiple rows, instead of columns, but generally this is the standard approach.

Additionally for querying the age, the best approach is to calculate a target date based on the current date and search for that, ensuring that indexes are usable on the dob column.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*), gender
FROM
  dependent
WHERE
  dob >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 21 YEAR)
GROUP BY gender;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

In your **where** clause, you seem to be subtracting a boolean from your date comparison, and then comparing that to 21.

How about `where YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(dob) < 21` or `where RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) - RIGHT(dob, 5) < 21`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT SUM(if(gender='M',1,0)) as males, SUM(if(gender='F',1,0)) as females 
FROM dependent
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 21 YEARS) < dob